# Facebook request for friends returns 0 friends when session is open

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am building an iOS application that is connected to Facebook. I got most of the Facebook related code (pretty much copied all of it) from the [TokenCacheHowTo](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.5-howtos/tree/master/TokenCacheHowTo) project. I have run into two problems, one which had a simple fix, but I think may be causing my second problem.

At first the login wasn't persisting. I had copied all the code from TokenCacheHowTo, so I was confused why and looked for a solution. Eventually I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642142/fb-ios-sdk-custom-token-caching-issue) and it said that if I removed `@[@"basic_info"]` from the permissions parameter it would work. And it did. I am still confused as to why it would work. Note: I removed `@[@"basic_info"]` from the `openSessionWithAllowLoginUI` method in my app delegate.

My problem now is that I want a list of the users friends, so I do the following request in the app delegate.

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Under");
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
}];
```

This code outputs `Found: 0 friends` within my app delegate, but if I put the code in the same place in TokenCacheHowTo it outputs `Found: X friends` where X is my actual number of friends. This is confusing to me because I am able to get the users information such as their id and name from Facebook and store it on my server.

I realize that there is probably a simple solution to this but I don't have a good grasp of the Facebook SDK yet and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as working fine for me and Ensure about the Permissions like

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_friends", nil];
```

and then fetch all the friend

```
-(void)getFriendList   {
    FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=friends.fields(first_name,last_name)" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                                  NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary* friendsDic = [result objectForKey:@"friends"];
        NSArray *friends = [friendsDic objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (NSDictionary *friend in friends) {
            NSLog(@"firstname %@",friend[@"first_name"]);
            NSLog(@"last name %@",friend[@"last_name"]);
        }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Nope. Nothing is printed because there is nothing in the dictionary.

Comment: @SamB But Working Fine for me

Comment: Ok, this works now! Why doesn't the TokenCacheHowTo have to do that?

Comment: @SamB `TokenCacheHowTo have to do that` means ?

Comment: Sorry, the TokenCacheHowTo project listed in the description of my problem doesn't have to specify permissions for "user_friends" to get a list of friends. I'm just grateful it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code. I've used the same code which you used above and I got `x friends list`. But my permission is declared as below

```
FBSession.activeSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me", @"email",@"user_birthday", nil]];
```

**Note:** I want email id and birthday from users that why my permissions include that fields.  And It should be declared before authentication, then only sessions kept this permission as it is.